Scan a page from a photo in the iOS Notes app
The Notes app has a nice feature to "scan" a letter by clicking the camera icon and selecting "scan document". This will use the camera, search for a letter-like object, correct tilt and optimize the picture and insert the result into the note.
Sometimes I have a picture of a piece of paper that I would like to transform in the same way. Unfortunately, it seems the Notes app only allows the camera as input to "scan document" and not a picture.
Is there a workaround to achieve the same result when the input is a picture?

Not being a notes user I an only suggest a "generic* workflow. Jjust take a picture and once it shows up in photos, long-press and copy it to then paste it into Notes.

Thanks @SteveChambers for your comment; I'm aware this is a possibility, but my target is to be able to extract a tilted and probably not ideally lit page from a picture and make it nice, in the same way the notes app would do that when using the "scan document" functionality.
